# How to reuse self tracking entities?

Tags: entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities

Among countless problems with STEs I am now facing this one, which should be trivial, but is not:

For simplicity, lets assume a standard invoice, order, product scenario.

Lets say that I have a non-stateless (for whatever reason) tier that receives an invoice and adds some orders for some products before sending the invoice back to the tier it came from.

This sounds simple, but is actually a problem with STEs that I have found no simple solution for. The problem is how to keep a collection of product entities to assign to the orders. As I see it I would have to do it in one of these ways, that all have major drawbacks:

**Query the database for a product entity for each order I want to place in the invoice-entity.**

Drawbacks: 
If the same product is used in several orders, EF will throw an exception, when the invoice changes are saved in the database, since multiple instances of the same product key is not allowed in the context. I could make sure that products occurring in multiple orders are only queried once and then shared among the orders, but it would definitely complicate things.

Another drawback is performance if the product entities (or equivalent entity in another domain scenario) are rather large or querying the database for products at the application tier is impractical for whatever reason.

**Query the database for all product entities at the beginning of the application lifetime**

This would be the typical scenario if you keep a list of products in a user application if the list of products rarely changes. In my case I don't want to query the database, since the "product" type list never changes in the lifetime of the application, performance is an important issue and the system should be robust to the database being temporarily unavailable, so I want to keep a cached collection of "product" equivalent entities.

Drawbacks: The major drawback here is that assigning cached products to new order entities will cause a memory leak. The reason for that is that the "Fixup" methods generated by the STE will hookup an event handler to the product's ChangeTracker in order to handle cascading deletions of a product. That event handler will keep the new order and the cached product connected accumulating all orders added for the lifetime of the cache.
A solution could be to implement some kind of "freeze" property of STEs, such that not only would change tracking be disabled, but the state of the entity and change tracker would remain unchanged even after navigation property assignments. Such a "freeze" modification could be difficult to write, since STE code comes with a lot of side effects making them hard to modify.

**Create product entity clones**

Here the products are being queried at the beginning of the application lifetime, but instead of using the product entities, clones are being made when assigning the products to the orders. This would solve the memory leak problem, but cloning would need to be implemented and maintained. It is possible that it would not be too hard rewriting the STE .tt scripts to support cloning. There would still be the problem with multiple entities in the entity context sharing the same key though.

Comment: I added EF 4 tag because by using only rarely visited tag you made your question unaswerable.